# Python based file searcher, for windows, for broken data sources in ArcMap Table of Contents

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

My goal is to have a program which can run in ArcMap, generate a .txt file of the missing data source names, then be extracted again (only data source names) to be used in a directory search, I have looked into os.walk, but am highly confused. So far what I have completed is a program which can run in ArcMap, to generate a .txt file of the missing data source names and original path. What I am lacking is the ability to extract only the data source names, and to search the entire directory for their current location, which would be written to another text file. Does anyone know if this is possible? So far my code is as follows:

```
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
#   Identifies broken file names in Table of Contents (TOC)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
    brokenlist = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)
    for brokenItem in brokenlist:
        arcpy.AddMessage(brokenItem.dataSource)

#   Path for writing .csv files and searching
    path = r"C:\ENGR597\Project"

#   Opens file to write
    f = open(path + '/Project_Test.txt', 'w')

#   Writes file for arcpy.AddMessage(brokenItem.name)
    for brokenItem in brokenlist:
        f.write(brokenItem.dataSource)

#   Opens text file to be read
    f= open('C:\ENGR597\Project\Project_Test.txt', 'r')

#   Extracts data source file name out to be used in a search (what I am missing)


#   Walks through directory to find file (preliminary code, that I was testing and didn't get far with)
    path = r"C:\ENGR597\Project"
    def walk_through_files(path, file_name='.pyt'):
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(file_extension):
                    yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    f = open(path + '/Project_Test2.txt', 'w')
                    f.write(dirpath, filename)
    return
```

Lastly, this is an example of the current text file (that needs to have just the source file names extracted for the search) that is generated when using the code:

```
C:\ENGR597\Project\GIS\Shapefiles\City and Town Points\City and Town 
Points.shpC
```

Thank you all in advance. I never though python would be such a headache.

Comment: The indent of your code snippet is not right, can you fix it?

Comment: This should get answered quicker at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.